# Chartjs tooltips disappear when calling Chart.update

Tags: chart.js

I have the goal of showing a tooltip on a near real-time chart that is updating constantly.

Using the standard tooltips in the `chartjs` library, calling `Chart.update()` will destroy the tooltip.

[In the example here](https://codepen.io/activedecay/pen/NBmQvv), if the user is hovering the chart, and the graph is updated, the tooltip goes away.

**Note:** if I change the chartjs version to `2.5.0`, there is no issue. It appears to be a bug in 2.7.2

How do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Right now there seems to be no official solution. There is still a discussion ongoing on how to fix this: [Do not hide tooltip when update is called](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5817)

Comment: That's interesting, because now the example I wrote doesn't exhibit the behavior previously observed. It's been so long, I don't know what's changed.